# iText keep all chunks in one line in PDF file

Tags: text, split, itext, chunks

I am writing a Java program to generate PDF file using iText.

I need to write the day, like "10th", with "st/nd/rd/th" superscript text just after the number. I create one chunk for the number and another chunk for the superscript text by calling setTextRise() function.

Then, I found that the number and the superscript text were split into two line. The number was placed at the end of line while the superscript text was placed at the beginning of the next line.

How can I keep these two chunk in one line?